# Is it possible to make a node optional in VB.NET XML Literals?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-literals

```
Dim task As XElement = <task>
                               <body>body</body>
                               <optional><%= myVar %></optional>

                           </task>
```

Is there anyway to remove `<optional>` when `myVar Is Nothing`?

Comment: Does it matter? You will simply have an empty node (`<optional />`, or more verbosely `<optional></optional>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IIf

```
    Dim task As XElement = <task>
                               <body>body</body>
                               <%= IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(myVar), "", <optional><%= myVar %></optional>) %>
                           </task>
```